# ¿Cómo instalar la librería de estilos PrimeNG o KendoUI en proyectos microfrontend angular con el framework Single-spa?

Tags: angular, primeng, kendoui

He estado intentando instalar las librerías **KendoUI** y **PrimeNG** en microfrontends creados con la librería **Single-SPA** de tipo Angular, pero no lo he logrado.

Funcionan en proyectos únicos de angular pero bajo el framework de **single-spa** yendo a la url del contenedor no, creo que tiene que ver con **webpack** mi problema pero no estoy seguro.

**¿Hay algún ajuste que deba realizar el proyecto contenedor de single-spa?**
**¿Tiene que ver con webpack? Si es así, ¿Cómo podría resolverlo?**

Cualquier ayuda será bienvenida, les agradezco su tiempo y respuesta!

En una prueba que hice creando un proyecto de Angular inicialmente antes de instalarle el framework de single-spa, si lograba instalar las librerías de forma correcta y se veía reflejado en el diseño, pero luego de configurar single-spa y asociarlos al proyecto contenedor ya se perdía el diseño de las librerías.

Con **kendoUI** instalo vía npm los componentes de la librería, luego verifico en los estilos de `angular.json` que estén allí las referencias a la librería y hago algunas pruebas, el proyecto angular como tál si me funcionan los componentes pero con el framework no:

- `npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-buttons`

```
"styles": [
{
   "input": "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.css"
},
   "src/styles.scss"
],
```

También intenté importando en `main.ts` la referencia a las librerías

```
import '@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.css';
import '@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css';
```

Con **PrimeNG** he hecho generalmente lo mismo que con KendoUI, instalé según su documentación, la librería vía npm e hice el paso a paso pero no se ve reflejado en el diseño la librería usando single-spa.

Answer (score 0):

Hola creo que debes arreglar tu `angular.json` y colocarlo asi

```
"styles": [
   "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.css",
   "src/styles.scss"
],
```

te muestro como tengo un proyecto

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/vela-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-spinner/animations/ball-scale-multiple.css"
            ],
```